# Why C++ implicit conversion works, but explicit one does not?

Tags: c++, c++11, casting, implicit-conversion, explicit-conversion

The following code compiles successfully in C++11:

```
#include "json.hpp"
using json = nlohmann::json ;

using namespace std ;

int main(){
    json js = "asd" ;
    string s1 = js ; // <---- compiles fine
    //string s2 = (string)js ; // <---- does not compile
}
```

It includes [JSON for Modern C++](https://github.com/nlohmann/json). A working example is in [this wandbox](https://wandbox.org/permlink/t5KzkBttFWuEY3DZ).

The JSON variable `js` is implicitly converted to a string. However, if I uncomment the last line, which is an explicit conversion, it fails to compile. Compilation results [here](https://wandbox.org/permlink/MK8U1Mtpl3Boh24S).

Beyond the particular nuances of this json library, how do you code a class so that an implicit conversion works but an explicit one does not?
Is there some kind of constructor qualifier that allows this behavior?

Comment: The issue I have with implicit conversions is that more often than not, the programmer is unaware of exactly what is going on, just that the conversion "worked".  You should debug the code that works and step in that call to see the actual sequence of events that is occurring in `string s1 = js;`  I wouldn't be surprised if it is much more than directly calling the `string` constructor (which you are trying to do with your commented line).

Comment: I have not verified but it probably use a template move constructor. `string s2 = move(js);` does compile.

Comment: In any case, you should not use C style cast and you should avoid unnecessary cast.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Here's a simplified code that reproduces the same issue:

```
struct S
{
    template <typename T>
    operator T() // non-explicit operator
    { return T{}; }
};

struct R
{
    R() = default;
    R(const R&) = default;
    R(R&&) = default;
    R(int) {} // problematic!
};

int main()
{
    S s{};
    R r = static_cast<R>(s); // error
}
```

We can see the compile error is similar:

```
error: call of overloaded 'R(S&)' is ambiguous
     R r = static_cast<R>(s);
                           ^
note: candidates...
     R(int) {}
     R(R&&) = default;
     R(const R&) = default;
```

The problem relies on the generic `S::operator T()`, which will happily return a value to whatever type you want. For example, assigning `s` to any type will work:

```
int i = s; // S::operator T() returns int{};
std::string str = s; // S::operator T() returns std::string{};
```

`T` is deduced to the conversion type. In the case of `std::string`, it has a lot of constructors, but if you do a [copy-initialization(1)](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/copy_initialization) of the form  `object = other`, `T` is deduced to the left-hand object's type (which is `std::string`).

Casting is another matter. See, it's the same problem if you try to copy-initialize using the third form (which in this case is a [direct initialization](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/direct_initialization)):

```
R r(s); // same ambiguity error
```

Okay, what are the constructor overloads for `R` again?

```
R() = default;
R(const R&) = default;
R(R&&) = default;
R(int) {}
```

Given that `R`'s constructors can take either another `R`, or `int`, the problem becomes apparent, as the template type deduction system doesn't know which one of these is the correct answer due to the context in which the operator is called from. Here, direct initialization has to consider all the possible overloads. Here's the basic rule:

> **A** is the type that is required as the result of the conversion. **P** is the return type of the conversion function template

In this case:

```
R r = s;
```

`R` is the type that is required as the result of the conversion (**A**). However, can you tell which type **A** will represent in the following code?

```
R r(s);
```

Now the context has `R` and `int` as options, because there is a constructor in R that takes integers. But the conversion type needs to be deduced to only one of them. `R` is a valid candidate, as there is at least one constructor which takes an `R`. `int` is a valid candidate as well, as there is a constructor taking an integer too. There is no winner candidate, as both of them are equally valid, hence the ambiguity.

When you cast your json object to an `std::string`, the situation is exact the same. There is a constructor that takes an string, and there is another one that takes an allocator. Both overloads are valid, so the compiler can't select one.

The problem would go away if the conversion operator were marked as `explicit`. It means that you'd be able to do `std::string str = static_cast<std::string>(json)`, however you lose the ability to implicitly convert it like `std::string str = json`.

Comment: Great answer, very well explained. Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

I think it is that when you use explicit conversion, the compiler have to choose from more function that when the code use implicit conversion.
When compiler found

```
string s1 = js
```

it exclude from overloading, all costructor and conversion marked "explicit" so it results to pick one function.
Instead when compiler found :

```
string s2 = (string)js ;
```

it must include all conversion and then the ambiguity.